# Get id of clicked element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a series of select boxes within a table. The html is:

```
<td id="1">
  <select id="a" name="xxx"> 
     <option ... </option>
  </select>
</td>

<td id="2">
   <select id="b" name="yyy"> 
     <option ... </option>
   </select>
</td>

... etc.
```

When a select box option is changed, how can i use jquery to return the id of the select box and the td?

I think it should be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('select').change(function() { 
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    return false; 
    });
});
```

Working [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/6Pq6F/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use on function with change event and find the td using the closest

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('select').on('change',function() { 
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var tdid = $(this).closest('td').attr('id');
            return false; 
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('select').change(function() { 
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var tdid = $(this).parent().attr('id'); // or $(this).closest('td').attr('id');
return false; 
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Vee4C/)

Answer (score 0):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7yvsz/)

Use **[`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** or **[`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)** to get reference to `<td>`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('select').change(function() { 
        var id = this.id;
        var tdId = $(this).closest('td').attr('id');  //or .parent()
        return false; 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.parent()` in jquery

```
$('select').change(function() { 
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
         var parentId = $(this).parent().attr('id');

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find parent td

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('select').change(function() { 
    var id = $(this).attr('id'); // id of select box
    var idOfTd = $(this).closest('td').attr('id');//id of td
    return false; 
    });
});
```